# Merge Cells in the Middle of Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I just want to ask if there is another way to merger cell in crystal report. What my report look like:

```
Name      Date      Percent       Rate      numberofMonths     Start      End
Juan   01-01-2019     60           70              2      01-01-2019 03-01-2019
Juan   02-01-2019     30           40              2
Juan   03-01-2019     30           50              2
```

What i want to happen is:

```
Name      Date      Percent       Rate      numberofMonths     Start      End
Juan   01-01-2019     60           70                   
Juan   02-01-2019     30           40              2     01-01-2019 03-01-2019
Juan   03-01-2019     30           50
```

I tried using group in crystal but it does not work the way i want it to work because in group all the cells that have duplicate value but what i want du suppress is just the number of months and start end date.

Comment: There is another columns after end i did not it because its too long.

Comment: Add suppress on this field and add formula to check the previous valuewith the current value.